# How do I set my bluetooth keyboard's layout setting?

Tags: keyboard-layout, bluetooth

I have upgraded to 11.10 and I have a HP Mini 2140 with a swiss layout keyboard. I could set that on the system setting and for the keyboard I have no problems. But I also use a Logitech DiNovo Edge bluetooth keyboard when I'm at home, and there is no way to set it in the right layout (the french swiss one).

How can I correct that? It's very strange because when I connect my Logitech keyboard is set on the American layout, but the one of the PC is still on the swiss french layout.

Comment: I've got the same problem with my Logitech DiNovo with German layout. Therefore I'm starting a bounty.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Old bluetooth pairings might not be 100% compatible with newer/upgraded Ubuntu 11.10.

Simply remove the keyboard from the list of paired devices, then "re-pair/reconnect" it.
Use the "connect" button underneath the keyboard.

Once it's been paired again, the correct layout should be active.

It's generally a good idea to unpair/re-pair all bluetooth devices after a system upgrade, as the bluetooth profiles and drivers has been updated.
New features won't activate until a device has been paired anew.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but re-pairing my keyboard doesn't solve the problem at all. Still blocked to the US-English layout.

Comment: I think that the problem come from the login page, when I log on using the laptop's keyboard, then I start using the bluetooth keyboard the layout is fine. If I login using directly my bluetooth keyboard, the one on the laptop doesn't work at all and the bluetooth one is stuck on the US-English layout.